# node-oauth Yahoo API oAuth2 issue

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, yahoo-api

I'm building an app with node.js and express.js. I'm using the node-oauth module to connect to yahoo so I can make get requests to the api. I keep getting the error below

```
{ statusCode: 401,
  data: '{"error":{"@lang":"en-US",
          "@uri":"http://yahoo.com",
          "description":"Not Authorized - Either YT cookies or a valid OAuth token must be passed for authorization","detail":"Not Authorized - Either YT cookies or a valid OAuth token must be passed for authorization"}}' }
```

After trying for a while to figure out my problem, I'm asking the community to check out my code and see what I am doing wrong. Code included below.

```
"use strict";

// declare libraries
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var OAuth = require('OAuth');

// set yahoo key and secret
var yahooKey = '*****************************************************';
var yahooSecret = '*********************************';

var oauth2 = new OAuth.OAuth2(
  yahooKey,
  yahooSecret,
  'https://api.login.yahoo.com/',
  'oauth2/request_auth',
  'oauth2/get_token',
  null
);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var access_token = oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
   '',
   {'grant_type':'authorization_code', 'redirect_uri':'http://www.domain.com'},
   function (e, access_token, refresh_token, results) {
    // console.log(e);
    // done();
  });
  // console.log(oauth);
  oauth2.get(
    'https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/circuitjump/profile?format=json',
    access_token,
    function (error, data, response){
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      // data = JSON.parse(data);
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(data, 0, 2));
      // console.log(response);
  });
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

// export route
module.exports = router;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. My brain is fried ...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some steps. I would direct you first to this guide:

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/

First, from your starting path at '/', you need to redirect (302) the user to an authorization page (Step 2 of yahoo's guide). The oauth lib has a helper for you to generate the correct URL:

```
var location = oauth2.getAuthorizeUrl({
    client_id: yahooKey,
    redirect_uri: 'https://yourservice.com/oauth2/yahoo/callback',
    response_type: 'code'
});
res.redirect(location);
```

What you just did there is you redirected the user's browser to yahoo's authorization page, where the user gets a dialog asking if they want to allow your service XYZ access to do stuff on the user's behalf. Upon clicking "Allow", yahoo will redirect the browser to your callback url (Step 3 of yahoo's guide), providing you with an `authorization code` in the query params. In this example you have hooked up at `/oauth2/yahoo/callback`

You can set that up like so (Step 4 of yahoo's guide):

```
router.get('/oauth2/yahoo/callback', function(req, res) {
    // Aha now I have an authorization code!
    var code = req.query.code;
    oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
        code,
        {
            'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': 'oob'
        },
        function(e, access_token, refresh_token, results) {
            console.log('Now I have a token', access_token, 'that I can use to call Yahoo APIs!');
            res.end();
        });
});
```

I hope all of that makes some sense. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out the refresh token (step 5). If you make it this far, that part should be easy :)

**Edit**

It looks like Yahoo also requires you to send your key and secret in a Authorization Basic header. You can generate this header and tell the oauth2 module to include it like so:

```
var encoded = new Buffer(yahooKey+":"+yahooSecret).toString('base64')
var authHeader = "Basic " + encoded;

var oauth2 = new OAuth.OAuth2(
  yahooKey,
  yahooSecret,
  'https://api.login.yahoo.com/',
  'oauth2/request_auth',
  'oauth2/get_token',
  { Authorization: "Basic " + authHeader}
);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch!!! this has gotten me almost all the way there. I still don't get an access_token but am now getting the authorization code. The error I'm getting is "{ statusCode: 400, data: '{"error":"invalid_request"}' }". Anyway, once I'm there I'll post back and I'll post what I did for step 5 :) thanks again

Comment: I think the issue might be that yahoo requires you to pass your yahoo key/secret via an `Authorization Basic` header on the `get_token` call. Unfortunately the npm oauth module assumes that you mean to send it in the post body https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/blob/a4b96a/lib/oauth2.js#L163

Comment: ...but you can specify it as part of the `customHeaders` option in the `OAuth2` constructor. I've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Hi Andrew, just wanna let you know I'll try out the changes this weekend and report back if it worked, how it worked etc etc.